# How to do filter and aggregation of nested objects on a 12 months from now with Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document of following mapping:

```
{
    "id": {"type": "integer"},
    "owner": {"type": "object"},
    "company_id": {"type": "integer"},
    "summary": {"type": "object"},
    "create_date": {"type": "date"},
}
```

So basically I want to filter id of owner and 12 months from now based on create_date. And then perform aggregate on keys inside summary objects.

Example of data I have:

```
id     |   owner                   | company_id    | summary                              | create_date
01     |   {"id": 1, "name": "x"}  | 1             | {"data1": 2, "data2": 5, "data3": 6} | "2020-09-22T01:04:17.852112Z"
02     |   {"id": 2, "name": "y"}  | 2             | {"data1": 2, "data2": 5, "data4": 6} | "2020-09-17T04:11:45.851231Z"
03     |   {"id": 3, "name": "z"}  | 3             | {"data1": 0, "data2": 4, "data3": 6} | "2019-02-02T12:19:27.852121Z"
```

Data as I want.

```
month-year                                       | aggregate of summary keys
09-2020 (any indicator/format of month and year) |{"data1":1, "data2": 5, "data3": 6, "data4": 6}
```

here data I want average of all the keys inside summary object according of every month of last 12 months.

Comment: Have you tried anything  ? i am adding an answer, but please do add details on what you have tried, as in public communities we do ask for help only after when we tried things at our end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 GET data/_search
{
  "size": 0, // <====== Represent that query o/p is not required, only aggs
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "create_date": {
              "gte": "now-6M" // <========== 'M' represent month, now represents current timestamp
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "owner.id": 4
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {   //<====== Custom name you can provide to this aggregation
      "terms": {    // <============ You need grouping based on the field and count of the grouped field will be returned
        "field": "summary.v1",
        "size": 10 // <==== How many data points needs to be returned
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Some details are added in the query. Other important things to learn :

1. [Queries & Filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-filter-context.html)
2. [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

---

**Edit:** Use below aggregation part in the existing query if you need monthly avgs.

```
"aggs": {
"monthly_grouping": {
 "date_histogram": {
   "field": "create_date",
   "interval": "month",
   "missing": "0"
 },"aggs": {
    "average_V1": {
      "avg": {
        "field": "summary.v1"
      }
    },
    "average_V2": { //<===== Similarly add other fields if required
      "avg": {
        "field": "summary.v1"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Read about [Date-Histogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) here.

Comment: Please do accept it as an answer , if it solves your problem.

Comment: You should use `filter` instead of `must` for filter queries.

Comment: thanks @Val . Due to the fact that filter context will be faster than query context ?

Comment: Due to the fact that scoring is not needed in this context, those constraints are just yes/no constraints

Comment: Can you please bit explain that aggregations block, I'm complete newbie for elasticsearch,  and also this is not reproducing result.

Comment: @rkisdp: I have added some details as comments.... for more details please read https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html.... Do let me know if it helps

Comment: @SahilGupta; Thank for you reply and help, but its still not generating aggregate result where as returning :- ```'aggregations': {'score_summary': {'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0, 'sum_other_doc_count': 0, 'buckets': [{'key': 2, 'doc_count': 3}]}}}```

Comment: aggregations of all the keys inside summary is required not of only one for the year wise filtered data

Comment: What do you mean by aggregation of all the keys.. Can you please add example in the description

Comment: @SahilGupta I have updated my question, you can check in Data as I want

Comment: By aggregate of summary keys.. U meant sum of values of each key?

Comment: average of values of all keys not sum

Comment: check now . Please be clear while asking questions on any public forums. Please don't forget to upvote and accept if it helps/works.